# To use strcpy or not

Tags: c

If I have an array of strings

```
char* q[2];
q[0] = "Hello";
q[1] = "World";
```

and I want to put `q[0]` in a new array of strings

```
char* x[2];
```

called x in x[0], should I use strcpy or just this?

```
x[0] = q[0];
```

This seems to work, but no using strcpy has caused some problems in the past.

Should I do this just in case? What is the difference?

```
char* a = malloc(strlen(q[0]) + 1);
strcpy(a, q[0]);
x[0] = a;
```

Comment: In you last example you probably wanted to add a `+1` to the size for `malloc`

Comment: "*I have an array of strings*" you haven't. `q` is an array of **pointers** to `char`. The two "string"s themself are constants literals, the elements two of `q` are pointing to ti their 1st element (`char`) each.

Comment: Understand the difference between arrays and pointers in C in general and understand how "strings" are mimicked in C using `0`-terminated `char`-arrays in particular, then your question becomes trivial.

Comment: They are literals, they are not going to change.  So copying the pointer is okay, saves you from the headache of figuring out when to call free().  Your strcpy version has the standard off-by-one bug, you need strlen() + 1 to store the zero terminator.

Answer (score 4):

The assignment works without allocating any extra memory.

If you use `strcpy()`, you have to assign enough memory to `x[0]` before you do the copy (`strlen(q[0]) + 1` bytes minimum), and you have to ensure it is released at the appropriate time.

Comment: So in this case, the assignment is better. How come my value changes sometimes when I don't use strcpy in other scenarios?

Comment: @melheitz We cannot tell which one is better. It depends on your usage of the arrays.

Comment: Probably (assignment is best) — but it depends on what you're going to do next with the variables.  As shown, the strings are string literals you shouldn't modify the strings pointed at by `q` (you should never edit string literals);.  If you plan to edit the strings in `x`, then you need to allocate space and copy the strings into that space.  If you plan to leave them alone, or perhaps change what is pointed to (change the pointer value, not the data that the pointer points at), then assignment is sufficient.

Comment: @melheitz : assignment is _cheaper_, but that is not the same thing as "better" - they have different semantics, and you need to use the one that suits.  Which is appropriate depends on what you are trying to do and you stated you wanted a _"new array of strings"_ which is not what pointer assignment will give you.  You might use that if your aim was to _sort_ the strings while maintaining an array in the original order, but if you intend to modify the strings, then you want copies as these are not modifiable.

Answer (score 3):

To be clear, there is nothing "broken" about `strcpy()`; if it has *"has caused some problems in the past"* for you, that that is because of errors in your usage, not any intrinsic issue with `strcpy()`, and you should perhaps post a question about that so your misconceptions can be corrected.

The semantics between *string pointer assignment* and *string copy* differ, so it depends what you are trying to do.

`x` is an array of pointers.  The assignment:

```
x[0] = q[0];
```

Does *not* copy the string pointed to by `q[0]` to the memory pointed to by `x[0]`.  rather it changes the value of `x[0]` to the address of the string referred to by `q[0]`. So they both refer to the *same string* in memory.  No string data is *moved* or *copied*, only the reference to the string literals in this case:

```
q[0] --> "Hello"
          ^
          |
x[0] -----
```

In this sense `x` is not *"a new array of strings"* as you describe, but an array of pointers to the *same strings*.  So is perhaps not the semantic behaviour you intended.

If you were to attempt:

```
strcpy( x[0], q[0] ) ;
```

That would be a semantic error since in your fragments `x[0]` does not point to any defined memory, so the string data referred to by `q[0]` will be *copied* to some undefined location with undefined results - none good, even if it superficially *appears* to work.

If `x[0]` referred to some validly allocated space by for example either being declared as an array thus:

```
char x[2][128] ;
```

or being dynamically allocated:

```
x[0] = malloc( 128 ) ;
```

or by first being assigned to some other valid space:

```
char a[120]
x[0] = a ;
```

Or by dynamically allocating `a` as in the example in your question.

Then `strcpy( x[0], q[0] )` is a valid operation and would *copy* the string referred to by `q[0]` to the space referred to by `x[0]`:

```
q[0] --> "Hello"

x[0] --> "Hello"
```

Critically in this case the strings do not refer to the same space in memory.

Note that if you actually wanted *string pointer assignment* semantics (which is probably less likely), and `q` refers to *literal string constants*, then for safer code it is important that you declare the arrays as pointers to `const` data:

```
const char* q[2] ;
const char* x[2] ;
```

The `q` array should be declared `const` in this case in any event, but clearly `x` should not be const if you want *string-copy* semantics.

Helpfully by declaring it `const`, any attempt to `strcpy()` to it will fail deterministicly at compilation rather than having some undefined and erroneous and possibly latent run-time behaviour.  So it enforces the intended semantics if that is indeed what you intended.  Equally it stops you from attempting to modify the data referred to by `q[n]` which would also be undefined behaviour (but will generally cause a runtime error on a modern desktop OS).

Answer (score 1):

There is no general rule, which one is better. This solely depends on your intented usage of the strings.

Simply assigning the pointer will work if you do not plan to modify the memory independently.

If you free the first pointer, you will still have a copy in the second pointer. But now it is invalid. Also if you add or change content via one pointer, this change will be visible via second pointer as well. This happens because you are using same memory.

If you copy the string, you have independend content. You can free or modify via the first pointer and still use it via second pointer.
Of course you also have to free the memory separately if you have copied to another location.

The simple assignment is faster, of course.
Which one is better depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an array of strings

Well, not quite. `q` is declared as

```
char* q[2];
```

Which makes it an array of two **pointers to `char`**. What is commonly referred to as a *string*, in C, is a NULL-terminated array of `char`.

Then, two values are assigned to each element of the array:

```
q[0] = "Hello";
q[1] = "World";
```

Where both `"Hello"` and `"World"` are **string literals**. No string is copied here, only the pointers.

Later in the code you could reassign each pointer, like in

```
q[0] = "Bye";
```

But any attempt to [modify the characters](https://wandbox.org/permlink/D49g4rXPixzQ6SO0) or [free the pointers](https://wandbox.org/permlink/c4bX9rTO6VgDiIcH) would lead to hard to detect bugs.

It would be safer to declare it as an array to pointer to **const** `char`, if they are meant to be untouched, so that, in case of mistakes, at least the error messages would be more informative. E.g [1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9T6OjTYqTQkWgBuu) or [2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/blkBNseAlWoyscHO).

If you need modifiable strings and the control of those objects lifetime, your only option is to allocate enough memory and copy the strings.